# How to split a string with blank lines between sections into a list containing each individual section C# .NET Framework 4.8

Tags: c#, cmd

I made a rookie mistake when working on this and made it in a .NET Core 6, without knowing those were two very different things which I now know, console program to make it easier to test before integrating it back into a .NET Framework 4.8 application. Then when I went to put it in the .NET framework 4.8 program the Split function was not excepting "\n\n" in order to split the sections properly and everything went downhill from there.

The goal of this is to be able to process the list of firewall rules on a given computer and check to see if all enabled file and printer sharing firewall rules have a matching block rule enabled. If any rules are enabled, but there is not a block rule of the same name as the enabled rule the given computer does not pass the audit.

Here is the .NET Core 6 version I got functioning properly.

```
Process process = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe")
        {
            WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Windows\System32",
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
            CreateNoWindow = false,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            Arguments = @"/c netsh advfirewall firewall show rule name=all verbose"
        });

        string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        output = output.Replace("\r\n", "\n");
        //splits each rule into its own section
        List<string> allSectionSplit = output.Split("\n\n").ToList();
        List<string> fileAndPrinterSharingSections = allSectionSplit.Where(x => x.StartsWith("Rule Name:                            File and Printer Sharing (")).ToList();
        Console.WriteLine(allSectionSplit.ElementAt(0));
        bool pass = false;
        //iterate through each rule section checking if its enabled. If is enabled we then have to traverse all the rules and check if we can find the block for that specific rule.
        foreach (string section in fileAndPrinterSharingSections)
        {
            pass = false;
            List<string> sectionLines = section.Replace(" ", "").Split("\n").ToList();

            //if a rule is enabled and allowed we must check that there is a block for that same rule that is enabled and blocked
            if (sectionLines.ElementAt(3) == "Enabled:Yes" && sectionLines.ElementAt(17) != "Action:Block")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(sectionLines.ElementAt(0) + "is enabled and allowed");
                //iterate again to try to find a matching block rule
                foreach (string searchSection in fileAndPrinterSharingSections)
                {
                    List<string> searchSectionLines = searchSection.Replace(" ", "").Split("\n").ToList();
                    //now we check if this section is the block for the enabled rule
                    if (searchSectionLines.ElementAt(3) == "Enabled:Yes"
                        && searchSectionLines.ElementAt(17) == "Action:Block"
                        && searchSectionLines.ElementAt(0) == sectionLines.ElementAt(0) //same rule name
                        )
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("passed - block found for allowed and enabled rule" + searchSectionLines.ElementAt(0));
                        pass = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("block not found for" + sectionLines.ElementAt(0));
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(section + "rule was not enabled and allowed");
                pass = true;
            } 
        }

        Console.WriteLine("passed =" + pass);
```

When you run `netsh advfirewall firewall show rule name=all verbose` in the command line it gives this output of all the rules for the computer that looks like this.
[image]

I then need to split that output into single sections (rules) like this, so I can further split it into individual lines within each section that way I can check things like the name of the rule, the action and if its enabled.
[image]

However, in .NET Framework 4.8 when I try and do .Split("\n\n") it doesn't except a string and wants a char, but if I try and turn it into a char array and then access it in my list via

```
List<string> sections = output.Split("\n\n".ToCharArray()).ToList();
            sections.ElementAt(0);
```

Nothing is returned at all.

Comment: What does `output.Split("\n")` do?

Comment: ```List<string> sections = output.Split('\n').ToList();
            sections.ElementAt(0);``` returns nothing. It wants me to do a single char it seems so I can't even do "\n".

Comment: How about [Environment.Newline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.newline?view=net-7.0)? You might need to cast it to a char array, but that property, by definition, should be the newline sequence for the current environment so it should work